# Writing to the database in a dialog based application created in MFC using ODBC

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I wrote a code to read from the database and its working. but when it i try to write to the database using AddNew(). but it gives the Debug Assertion Error. here is the code that i am trying

```
void CReadDBDlg::OnRead() 
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
CDatabase database;
CString SqlString;
CString sCatID, sCategory;
CString sDriver = "MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)";
CString sDsn;
CString sFile = "d:\\Test.mdb";
// You must change above path if it's different
int iRec = 0;   

// Build ODBC connection string
sDsn.Format("ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s",sDriver,sFile);
TRY
{
    // Open the database
    database.OpenEx(NULL,false,false,sDsn);

    // Allocate the recordset
    CRecordset recset( &database );

    // Build the SQL statement
    SqlString =  "SELECT CatID, Category "
            "FROM Categories";

    // Execute the query
    recset.Open(CRecordset::snapshot,SqlString,CRecordset::appendOnly);

    // Loop through each record

        // Copy each column into a variable
        recset.GetFieldValue("CatID",sCatID);
        recset.GetFieldValue("Category",sCategory);

        // goto next record
        recset.MoveLast();
        recset.GetFieldValue("CatID",sCatID);
        //recset.AddNew();

    // Close the database
    database.Close();
}
CATCH(CDBException, e)
{
    // If a database exception occured, show error msg
    AfxMessageBox("Database error: "+e->m_strError);
}
END_CATCH;
}
```

Comment: the database we are using is MS Acess

Comment: And the code is written in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the database in snapshot mode - that is read-only. You need to open it as a dynaset:

```
recset.Open(CRecordset::dynaset...)
```

Comment: when we use dyanset it gives this exception that "ODBC driver does not support dynaset"

Comment: The MSDN help says snapshots are are update-able as well. But when we try to open in Snapshot it gives an exception that No columns were bound prior to SQL fetch. Could any1 help with that?

Comment: What Access version are you using, and are you including the "primary" key from the Categories table? I see you got CatID, but is it really the primary key in the table?